# How to describe actions towards realizing a goal

Tags: phrase-requests, verbs, phrasal-verbs

I am struggling to find the right verb to describe taking actions to realize a goal.

Specifically, here is a sentence I am trying to write in an elegant and terse manner :

> The government first decides what the public good is, and then acts
> towards **realizing** it.

That feels wrong as "realizing the public good" does not really make sense.

I could say :

"The government first decides what the public good is, and then acts towards making it a reality."

But I would much prefer to have a more specific and descriptive verb, or turn of phrase. Indeed that would be useful in other contexts as well.

Such a verb would also be useful in a sentence following the previous one, for example:

> They delegated the job to determine what the public good is to
> commission A, and the job to **realize** it to commission B.

Again, *realize* is wrong here, and I am trying to find the correct verb.

Comment: ... *and then aims to achieve it.* But, "the public good" isn't itself an aim or realisation: a government takes measures which *themselves* are "in the public good."

Comment: I would suggest that your problem is with “public good”. This is an abstract concept which can be descriptive of a concrete situation. It is that situation that government policies in the public good aim to achieve or realize — not the public good. So I think you need to go back to the drawing board. Exactly what @WeatherVane wrote while I was writing this.

Comment: @David, yes I had edited the previous comment.

Comment: ah, that's a great point. My problem is that I need to keep the term "public good" (it is a key term in the essay that I am working on).

Comment: If the government decides what the public good is and then sets about making that happen (it could conceivably choose one of many measures of prosperity, health, or success), then "realize" is fine. It would help if you were more concrete on what you mean by "public good" though - is there one or many? is it something very abstract like GDP, something concrete like [woodland](https://ostromworkshop.indiana.edu/pdf/seriespapers/2015s_c/Watkins_paper.pdf), or something in between like a health service?

Comment: I do not understand what you think is wrong with 'realise'.  There is a perfectly good use of that verb, meaning 'bring about'.  There is a problem with 'the public good', that it sounds as if it might consist of one single thing, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @Tuffy I see. So maybe I can keep "realize" but change the phrasing in the first part of the sentence. I would like to keep the words "Public Good", but maybe I can rephrase it?

Comment: @StuartF yes, this is something very abstract, which essentially mean happiness of people, in general.

Comment: "The government first decides what maximizes the Public Good, and then realize it" -> does that make sense?

Comment: Which definition of [public good](https://www.google.com/search?gl=gb&hl=en&q=define+public%20good&forcedict=example&dictcorpus=en&expnd=1) are you using?

Comment: @TinfoilHat the second one : "the benefit or well-being of the public."

Comment: II just have to say it. I really think I have come up with the best answer. Doesn't it jump out at you? :) If it doesn't, I will not go out into the garden and eat worms.

Comment: I am not able to ask more questions because my questions do not get upvotes :( I actually think my question is not completely unreasonable. Can anyone find it in their heart to upvote it or guide me towards phrasing my question better in order to be upvoted?

Comment: Many questions asking for a single word are completely ridiculous. This one is not. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @DEvShark  I should have thought that specific aims or objectives which contribute to the Public Good are what you would be trying to fulfil, achieve or, yes, realise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question sentence: The government first decides what the public good is, and then acts towards realizing it.

I would use:

**takes action to achieve it.**
Or: **implements policies to achieve it.**

Just one example from among more than 700, 000 examples via google:

> Government failures where officials seek the public interest. In order
> to understand the most important types of governmental failure, assume
> for the moment that the government actors are public spirited. That
> is, assume that the people drafting and enforcing the rules are
> competent, well-informed, and wish to **achieve the public good** in the
> area of privacy protection. Even under these optimistic assumptions,
> government privacy regulation will lead to administrative costs on
> government and taxpayers, and compliance costs on industry. [bolding mine]

[theory of markets and privacy](https://www.ntia.doc.gov/page/chapter-1-theory-markets-and-privacy)

Couldn't resist posting another one:

> Reflecting on the growing control of markets over societies, he [Professor Michael Sandel] said:
> “Reagan and Thatcher introduced the idea that market mechanisms are
> the primary instruments for **achieving the public good**. When the
> financial crisis came many of us assumed that now finally would come a
> robust public debate about the proper reach of money and markets in
> society. But it came and went and we haven’t seen in democratic
> societies a more fundamental debate about where markets serve the
> public good and where they don’t belong.” [bolding mine]

[Oxford Martin School](https://www.oxfordmartin.ox.ac.uk/news/201605-michael-sandel/)

Comment: Ah nice. I thought "to achieve the public good" does not make sense, but apparently it is a valid thing to say. Does this phrase sound natural to your hear? Or is it only a literary one?

Comment: @DevShark All of the options are formal English. It is not literary per se. The word achieve is used in many, many contexts including education, government and business. The two examples I quoted are pretty much your context. :)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. That is perfect for my use case.

Comment: When I see the word shark, all I can think of is that kids' song. Baby Shark. :) :) It drives me nuts.

Comment: Haha, nice. That's good, it brings a little music in this world then :D

Answer (score 0):

Arguably it's a bit dated (it's [*far* less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=promote%20the%20public%20good&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) than it was a couple of centuries ago), but...

> *The government first decides what the public good is, and then acts to **promote** it.*

> **promote** <sup><sub>[(Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/promote)</sub></sup>
> *to encourage the **existence or development** of something*

---

For OP's second example, ***promote*** is still fine if you don't mind interpreting it from a somewhat Victorian perspective (the *modern* ear would more likely assume the *promotion = **advertising*** sense). But I'd prefer a different verb there...

> *They assigned the job of determining what the public good is to Commission A, and the job of **implementing** it to Commission B*

Note that I see nothing wrong with ***realising*** there, and I don't really have a preference for one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

**implement**

other examples:

1. Leadership is about the ability to implement change.
2. He tried to implement a technocratic economic policy.
3. It's still not clear how far the Russian parliament will go to
   implement its own plans.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a phrase would offer you more room to be specific:

> The government first decides what
> the public good is, then takes
> steps towards its fulfillment.

Answer (score 0):

**Undertake** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undertake))

(transitive) To take upon oneself; to start, to embark on (a specific task etc.).

(intransitive) To commit oneself (to an obligation, activity etc.).

> The government first decides what the public good is, then undertakes
> to implement/realise/accomplish/attain it.

You can also say

> The government first decides what the public good is, then starts its
> implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**materialize** should work well in the given context.

Here's *The American Heritage Dictionary*:

> To cause to become real Or actual

*By building the house, we materialized a dream.*